# Groupby in R to fill a new table and while changing row names

Tags: r

I had question regarding filling a data.frame using values from the data.table.  I have gotten stuck withba data.table `a` where I have  4 columns and I need to select the max `Average` and return the `value` in a new data.frame `z`.  From data.frame `a` I am using `Average` to select `Value` to put into `z`.  The way I was trying to set it up was if Average > 80 than select and repeat value for row `a` and `red_a` and `red_b` else use `Average[1]`==highest Average and `Average[2]` == 2nd largest value to select the `Values`.Is there a way to automatically generate a red_a and red_b without and filling a table easily that I missing.  I was to get the max but have been stuck at using a single value to fill a table.  I put what I have tried so far with data.tables.

**Example data set**

```
set_a <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c")
set_b <- c("red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red")
value <- c(42,68,90,91,22,65,89,98,78,88,91,33)
Average <- c(94,3,2,1,50,40,5,5,80,9,1,1)
a = data.frame(set_a,set_b,value,Average)
```

**Desired output**

```
z <- data.frame(set_a = c("a","a","b","b"),set_b = c("red_a","red_b","red_a","red_b"),value = c(42,42,22,65))
library(reshape2)
example <- acast(z,set_a ~ set_b, value.var = "value")
red_a red_b
a    42    42
b    22    65
```

**R used so far:**
I have been able to get the max value but have trouble setting it up to get the second value.

```
a = data.frame(set_a,set_b,value,Average)
library(data.table)
a = data.table(a)
y =a[,max(na.omit(Average)), by=.(set_a,set_b),all=T]
y


mydata2 = merge(a[0], y, by.x = c("set_a","set_b"),by.y = c("set_a","set_b"),all=TRUE)
mydata2
y$match <- a$value[match(y$V1,a$Average)]
y$V1 <- NULL
library(reshape2)
set_matrix = acast(y, set_a ~ set_b, value.var = "match")
set_matrix
```

Comment: what about `c`?

Comment: @Frank I forgot to a would be the repeat of the maximum value if the value from A if average was greater than 80 else take the first and second value.

Comment: that wld be good info to add to the actual question

Comment: @hrbrmstr c is what is use to select the value in the table.  If Average is greater than 80 for example I was using the maxium value to set red_a and red_b.  If was less than 80 and red_a and red_b would be the highest average and 2nd highest average.

Comment: that would also be good into to add to the question.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I'll edit